# Print multiple glossaries on one page

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package to have three glossaries: the main(default) one, the acronym, and the symbol one. As all three are to long with each taking a new page on its own I would like to shrink them all on one page. But the default behaviour seems to be a pageskip after each defined glossar. 
How two prevent this and get them on one page (multiple if not enough space). Look like:
[image] 
 This is the MWE:

```
    \newcommand{\TWOorONESIDE}{oneside} % According to above twoside/oneside (unsymmetric/symmetric margins)
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn,notitlepage,\TWOorONESIDE]{book}
%NOTE Packages, my Macros und Formatdefinitions
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}  % Multilingual support ctan.org/pkg/babel?lang=en
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Allows different font encodings and hyphenation ctan.org/pkg/fontenc?lang=en
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Translates input encodings into LaTeX internal language
\usepackage{hyperref}   % Extensive Cross-ref­er­enc­ing com­mands ctan.org/pkg/hyperr
\usepackage[acronyms,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\newglossary*{mysyms}{Symbolverzeichnis}    % custom glossary, type=mysmys
\makenoidxglossaries    
% some entries:
\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},plural={potatoes}, description={starchy tuber}} 
\newglossaryentry{cabbage}{name={cabbage},description={vegetable with thick green or purple leaves}}
\newglossaryentry{ROS_def}{name={ROS},description={Operating system connecting various C++ nodes}}
%... glossary
\newacronym{ac:ros}{ROS}{Roboter Operating System}
\newacronym{ac:svm}{SVM}{support vector machine}
%... acronyms
\newglossaryentry{R}{type=mysyms,name={R},description={rational number amount}} 
%...symbols

%begin document env.
\begin{document}
        \textit{Alle} Ausführungen, die wörtlich oder sinngemäß übernommen wurden, sind als 
        solche gekennzeichnet.\\
        test \gls{R}, test \gls{ac:ros}, test \gls{ROS_def}, test \gls{cabbage}, \\
        eine \gls{potato}.\\
        \vspace{20mm}   \\
\printnoidxglossaries   % Shortcut to display all glossaries at once 
\end{document}
```

I did search the [docs](http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) but could not find anything helpful. Has anyone solved that before?

Comment: A compilable document would be really nice ;-)

Comment: And if I use your 'document' I get **one** page

Comment: I did include a mwe, in case of twoside option it even skips a whole page (which was mentioned within the docs);

Comment: That `\TwoOrONESIDE` code looks weird. Most likely `ngerman` is the better option to `babel`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `\setglossarysection{section}`, i.e. each glossaries is an unnumbered section instead of a chapter (since `book` class) is used.

The `\printnoidxglossaries` command might need a `\clearpage` before, to the the glossaries on a new page (but all of them on the same page)

```
\newcommand{\TWOorONESIDE}{oneside} % According to above twoside/oneside (unsymmetric/symmetric margins)
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn,notitlepage,\TWOorONESIDE]{book}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}  % Multilingual support ctan.org/pkg/babel?lang=en
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Allows different font encodings and hyphenation ctan.org/pkg/fontenc?lang=en
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Translates input encodings into LaTeX internal language
\usepackage{hyperref}   % Extensive Cross-ref­er­enc­ing com­mands ctan.org/pkg/hyperr
\usepackage[acronyms,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\setglossarysection{section}
\newglossary*{mysyms}{Symbolverzeichnis}    % custom glossary, type=mysmys
\makenoidxglossaries    
% some entries:
\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},plural={potatoes}, description={starchy tuber}} 
\newglossaryentry{cabbage}{name={cabbage},description={vegetable with thick green or purple leaves}}
\newglossaryentry{ROS_def}{name={ROS},description={Operating system connecting various C++ nodes}}
%... glossary
\newacronym{ac:ros}{ROS}{Roboter Operating System}
\newacronym{ac:svm}{SVM}{support vector machine}
%... acronyms
\newglossaryentry{R}{type=mysyms,name={R},description={rational number amount}} 
%...symbols

\begin{document}
\textit{Alle} Ausführungen, die wörtlich oder sinngemäß übernommen wurden, sind als 
solche gekennzeichnet.\\
test \gls{R}, test \gls{ac:ros}, test \gls{ROS_def}, test \gls{cabbage}, \\
eine \gls{potato}.\\
% \vspace{20mm}   \\
\clearpage
\printnoidxglossaries   % Shortcut to display all glossaries at once 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wonder where the \setglossarysection{section} is coming from. TexStudio does not accept nor can i find it [here] (http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html) <br> Undefined control sequence. \setglossariessection, oh found it :), lets see

Comment: It's in `glossaries`, of course, but I made a typo: I meant `\setglossarysection`. The code had the right version

Comment: yep, now I can find it, furthermore using `section` within the usepackage option is also possible. Thank you (not enough rep to upvote )

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the package option. Sometimes it's better to provide some settings later on, not right from the start, using `\set....` etc. macros